# Google Admob Integration Error in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, admob

**Google Admob Integration Error in iOS**

I am using GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-6.12.2 latest version downloaded from https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download.

- If I run on iOS 7.x, I am getting the following errors.

  1) CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-108)

  2) NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -108)
- If I run on iOS 8.x, I am getting **Crash** due to "com.apple.nsurlconnectionloader exc_bad_access" error.

**Added below code for integrate Google Admob.**

```
GADBannerView *bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,self.view.frame.size.height -GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];//Set Position

bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716";

bannerView.rootViewController = self;

GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, @"MY_TEST_DEVICE_ID" ];

[bannerView loadRequest:request];
```

Anyone please help me to get out of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, It is because of the Network blocker issue.
If I run this code in my office, I am getting these type of errors.
If I run same on my home, It is working fine.
Because in my office they are blocking adds.
So I asked my N/W admin to allow adds on my system, He allowed, My issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It is a network not getting error.Please check any blocking or Proxy.